# Record separate audio inputs as separate tracks in OBS Studio

Tags: audio, microphone, obs-studio

I record myself playing a game using OBS Studio.

What I want to do is also record microphone input, but instead of having the audio of my speakers and mic on the same audio track, I want to have a track with just my speaker audio in the video file, with my microphone input on a separate track in order to make "editing" microphone input easier if needed.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://obsproject.com/wiki/Advanced-Recording-Guide-With-Multi-Track-Audio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly possible in OBS.

First select the audio mixer, if you don't have it open you'll need to open it.
[image: Audio Mixer in OBS Studio]

Then click on the cog "advanced audio settings"

[image: Advance Audio Settings in OBS Studio]

On number 1 make sure everything is ticked.  That will be for Streaming.

On the other numbers make sure each audio source (input or output) has their own unique number as you can see in my screenshot.

I have a separate audio channel for each input or output source.  So only 1 source has the number 2, only once source has the number 3, etc.

Comment: Important to record in a format that maintains the channels so that you can play with them later in your editor.

Comment: Good point @BodgeIT I usually use the default which I believe is MKV.  MP4 would not work so far as I'm aware.